# Determine the Highest and Lowest per row in array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please help me on this, I already have a code and it runs perfectly but the thing is I need to determine the Highest and Lowest per row. I don't know how to start, please help me and also please explain to me. here is the code:

```
int [][] num = {{1,4,3,0,5},{2,4,7,8,10},{3,9,60,20,4}};
int row, col;
for (row=0;row<3;row++){
    int sum = 0;
    for (col=0;col<5;col++){      
        System.out.print(num[row][col]+"|");
        sum =sum+num[row][col];
    }
    System.out.println("sum = "+sum); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
int [][] num = {{1,4,3,0,5},{2,4,7,8,10},{3,9,60,20,4}};
int row, col;
for (row=0;row<3;row++){
colcount = 0; //count if is the first column
mincol = 0;
maxcol = 0;
for (col=0;col<5;col++){    

    if(colcount == 0){ //if first time at the loop
        mincol = num[row][col]; //mincol will be the first column
        maxcol = num[row][col]; //maxcol will be the first column
        colcount++;
    }else{
        mincol = (mincol < num[row][col]) ? mincol : num[row][col]); //will verify if the mincol is really the lowest. If true, will maintain the mincol value.. else .. will get the current column.
        maxcol = (maxcol > num[row][col]) ? maxcol : num[row][col]); //same of mincol, but using maxcol.
    }
}
```

}

you can put the max and min col into an array.. it's up to you.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It is really similar to what you already have.

1. Create variables to hold your `min` and `max` values instead of `sum`.
2. Assign the first item in the row to both `min` and `max` (since that is the highest and lowest number so far).
3. For each new number after the first, check if it is lower than `min` or higher than `max`, and in that case save that instead.

Comment: No spoon-feeding - apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    int [][] num = {{1,4,3,0,5},{2,4,7,8,10},{3,9,60,20,4}};
    for (int[] row : num) {
        int lowest=row[0], highest=row[0];
        for (int i : row) {
            if (i<lowest) {
                lowest=i;
            }
            if (i>highest) {
                highest=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Lowest:"+lowest+"; Highest:"+highest);
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: please do not make SO a code factory. Would really appreciate if you give the algo in such simple problems so that OP can work it out.

Comment: And who are you to say that?

Answer (score 0):

Creating `low` and `high` outside of the loop so they can be accessed throughout (i.e. later on in the program).

```
int low = -1;
int high = -1;

for(int n = 0; n < 3; n++) {
    int[] temp = num[1];
    for(int m : temp) {
        if(low == -1) {
            low = m;
        }

        if(high == -1) {
            high = m;
        }

        if(m < low) {
            low = m;
        } else if(m > high) {
            high = m;
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if it can be optimised further, but hey.

Comment: after the first row ,i second loop your code will check with previous highest and lowest values

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
   int [][] num = {{1,4,3,0,5},{2,4,7,8,10},{3,9,60,20,4}};

int row, col;

        for (row=0;row<3;row++){
            int sum = 0;
            int high=0,low=999999;
            for (col=0;col<5;col++){      
        System.out.print(num[row][col]+"|");
        sum =sum+num[row][col];
        if(num[row][col]>high)
        {
        high=num[row][col];
        }
        if(num[row][col]<low)
        {
        low=num[row][col];
        }
        }
        System.out.println("sum = "+sum); 
            System.out.println("higest:"+high+" and lowest="+low);
        }
    }
```

on each iteration just check each item and store it in two variables high AND low.
for each loop we compare the values with high and low and change.

Answer (score 0):

try this....

- Use a temporary array to sort each row.
- Use that array to find the max and min values of each row.

  int[][] num = {{1, 4, 3, 0, 5}, {2, 4, 7, 8, 10}, {3, 9, 60, 20, 4}};

  ```
  int row, col;        
  for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
      int temp[]=num[row];        
      int sum = 0;
      for (col = 0; col < temp.length; col++) {
          for(int j=0;j<temp.length;j++){
               if(temp[col]<temp[j]){
                   int a=temp[col];
                   temp[col]=temp[j];
                   temp[j]=a;                     
               }

          }

      }
     System.out.println("ROW"+row+": min="+temp[0]+" max="+temp[temp.length-1]);
  }
  ```